# Razor Engine - how to escape @ within quotes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I need to create this output via RazorEngine:

```
<element attr1="@SomeText"></element>
```

So in my cshtml file I typed up this:

```
<element attr1="@@@Model.SomeProp"></element >
```

The problem I'm facing is that escaping @ with @@ causes an error in RazorEngine.

Before you suggest "& #64;" I must add that

```
<element attr1="&#64;SomeText"></element>
```

will not do in my case (don't ask me why)

What can you suggest as a solution?

Nothing comes to mind other than creating a global constant and using it thus

```
<element attr1="@Class1.At@Model.SomeProp"></element >
```

PS: The error I'm getting is:

> Parser Error Message: "@" is not valid at the start of a code block. 
>   Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Comment: So is this just some static text that you want to set the attribute value to or is the value coming from a property of your view model?

Comment: What error are you getting? That should work.

Comment: Why can't you use the symbol code?

Comment: So you have a Model with a property of `SomeProp` and you want to output that property value prefixed with `@`?

Comment: I cannot use the symbol code because it's not going to be used in a browser - it's going to be used by another app that unfortunately doesn't understand the symbol code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<element attr1='@Html.Raw("@")@Model.PortNumber'></element>
```

Comment: Thanks! 
This works. I didn't think to use @Html.Raw("@") in place of "@"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<element attr1="@("@SomeText")"></element>
```

Answer (score 0):

My original answer would be to output the @ using the symbol code `&#64;`
http://character-code.com/

However since you *"can't"* then maybe Html.Raw?

```
<element attr1="@Html.Raw("@SomeText")"></element>
```

Comment: I would suggest placing only `@SomeText` into the `Raw`, not the whole element.